# How to copy/paste a shortcut to all users quick launch toolbar?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, terminal-services

I'm trying to figure out a way to add ONE new shortcut icon to all 40 user's quick launch toolbar without having to manually paste into 40 folders.

Comment: If you were to do this for *one* user, what folder would you put it in? What about using the "All Users" folder located in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users?

Answer (score 0):

On windows XP (ignore unix folder-separators):

```
Documents and Settings/Default User/Programdata/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Quick Launch
```

I think it's safe to assume that a similar path (c:/users/all users ..or something) applies to Windows Vista and Windows 7 with IE 8 or even newer.